# How do you avoid a possible race condition with firebase cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I have a cloud function that is triggered by a Firestore database write. It does an async operation (fetch data from some 3rd party API's) that may take a long time, might not. When it's finished, it writes the result to a 'search result' field.

There's a possible race condition where the result from a newer trigger gets overwritten by an older operation that finishes this later. How should I solve this problem in the context of Firebase cloud functions and Firestore?

Comment: What do you intend to do if you know that a request to the third party service is currently happening during a second (or third, or fourth) Firestore document write?

Comment: Cancel it, if not ignore and unsubscribe.

Comment: Cancel the old request, I mean. Not cancel the new database write.

Comment: Two invocations of a function know nothing of each other.  They may not even be running on the same server instance.  One invocation cannot affect another without some fairly deep work to try to set up some communication between the two, probably using Firestore itself.

Comment: Typically you'd do this by ensuring that operations are idempotent, meaning that performing the same operation multiple times is a noop. How to do this depends on your specific use-case though.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In general there are two approaches here:

1. Ensure your operations are idempotent
2. Ensure your operations detect conflicting updates and retry

#### Ensure your operations are idempotent

This is often the most scaleable and architecturally simple. When you perform the same idempotent operation on the same input, it has the same result. This means that it doesn't matter if the operation is performed multiple times, as the result will be the same.

A good example of this is in the [Firestore documentation on arrays and sets](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays). Imagine that you're tagging blog posts with categories. A naïve model for this would be:

```
{
    title: "My great post",
    categories: [
        "technology",
        "opinion",
        "cats"
    ]
}
```

But now imagine that two users are tagging the same post as being about cats at almost the same time. You might end up with

```
{
    title: "My great post",
    categories: [
        "technology",
        "opinion",
        "cats",
        "cats"
    ]
}
```

Which is clearly not what you wanted. But since the data structure allows it, this may happen. The ideal solution here is to use a data structure that makes this impossible: a data structure where adding `cat` is an idempotent operation. In mathematical terms this would be a set, and in Firestore you'd model that as:

```
{
    title: "My great post",
    categories: {
        "technology": true,
        "opinion": true,
        "cats": true
    }
}
```

Now in this structure, it doesn't matter how often you set `cats` to `true`, the result will always be the same.

#### Ensure your operations detect conflicting updates and retry

Sometimes it isn't possible (or feasible) to make your operations idempotent. In that case, you can also consider using a compare-and-set strategy.

For example, say that the 3rd party API changes the data in some way, and that you want to only write the result back to the database if the original data in the database is unmodified. In that case you'll want to take these steps in your function:

1. read the original data
2. call the 3rd party API with the data
3. wait for the result
4. start a transaction
5. load the original data again
6. if the data has been modified go back to #2
7. if the data was not modified write the result from the 3rd party API

This type of compare-and-set operation is actually how Firebase's Realtime Database implements transactions, with the "3rd party API" being your applications transaction handler.

As you can probably see this second approach is more complex than the approach with idempotent operations. So when possible, I'd always recommend that approach.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have to do some deep thinking on this.

Comment: Good idea.
The problem with the solution above is that if I want to use `array-contains` (Firestore query operator) then I can't with the above solution as it only works for array and not object

Comment: Firebase now supports arrayUnion and arrayRemove for idempotent array operations. See: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/better-arrays-in-cloud-firestore.html

Answer (score 1):

Although not a direct answer to the OP's question regarding waiting for a 3rd party response, for those who came here from a Google search for a generalized Firestore race condition solution, Firestore supports both transactions and batched writes:

> Cloud Firestore supports atomic operations for reading and writing data. In a set of atomic operations, either all of the operations succeed, or none of them are applied. There are two types of atomic operations in Cloud Firestore:
>
> - Transactions: a transaction is a set of read and write operations on one or more documents.
> - Batched Writes: a batched write is a set of write operations on one or more documents.

For more details, see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

Answer (score -1):

Firebase cloud function provides transact() function and that could be used just to save some data onto database atomically.